# Selecting columns from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display two columns from my attendance table (MEMBER_ID & MEETING_ID) and one column from my meeting table and finally two columns from my member table which displays the names that match with MEETING_ID.

The attendance table has a composite key (MEMBER_ID*, MEETING_ID*)

The member table's primary key is MEMBER_ID

Meeting table's primary key is MEETING_ID

My attempt is not working, can someone please help?

```
SELECT MEMBER_ID, MEETING_ID, MEETING_NAME MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, MEMBER_LASTNAME
FROM ATTENDANCE, MEMBER, MEETING
WHERE MEETING.MEMBER_ID = MEETING.MEMBER_ID;
```

End result needs to be:

```
MEMBER_ID    MEETING_ID   MEETING_NAME     FIRSTNAME    LASTNAME
0001         MEET0004     SPORTS DAY      JOHN         SMITH
```

Comment: A few things... the WHERE clause as you wrote it is always true, so you may as well delete it. You probably meant MEETING.MEMBER_ID = ATTENDANCE.MEMBER_ID; but you also need a join condition between ATTENDANCE and MEMBER. Then, it will be better if you use the SQL Standard join syntax (ATTENDANCE join MEETING on (condition) join MEMBER on (condition)...). Finally, do you need just one row in the result, or ALL the matching rows? If only one row, you are probably missing some WHERE condition(s), like MEMBER_ID = ... Oh, and in the SELECT you need to state from which table you want the fields

Comment: I understand FallAndLearn's answer works for you but you really should start using Explict Join Syntax rather than implicit because you cannot do an outer join with Implicit and because Explicit has been in existence as an ANSI standard for decades now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need this.

```
SELECT A.MEMBER_ID, A.MEETING_ID, M2.MEETING_NAME, M1.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M1.MEMBER_LASTNAME
FROM ATTENDANCE A, MEMBER M1, MEETING M2
WHERE M1.MEMBER_ID = A.MEMBER_ID
AND A.MEETING_ID = M2.MEETING_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.MEMBER_ID
    ,a.MEETING_ID
    ,mt.MEETING_NAME
    ,mb.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME
    ,mb.MEMBER_LASTNAME
FROM
    ATTENDANCE a
    INNER JOIN MEMBER mb
    ON a.MEMBER_ID = mb.MEMBER_ID
    INNER JOIN MEETING mt
    ON a.MEETING_ID = mt.MEETING_ID
;
```

Use Explicit Join Syntax and then setup your relationships using the ON conditions and the keys between the tables.  Note I also used table aliases to shorten typying.